# Using sed to remove all lines after last time specific string is mentioned in TXT

Tags: ubuntu, sed, replace

I have a file that looks like this:

```
Apple prices
$15.74 p 12
$13.17 p 12
$8.19 p 8
Apple prices
$12.99 p 11
$4.67 p 1
$3.22 p 2
Apple prices
$3.99 p 1
$4.65 p 2
$2.19 p 1
```

I want a single line sed command that removes everything after the last time 'Apple prices' is mentioned. So the result would be:

```
Apple prices
$15.74 p 12
$13.17 p 12
$8.19 p 8
Apple prices
$12.99 p 11
$4.67 p 1
$3.22 p 2
```

In sed, I tried using `'/Apple prices/q2'` but that removes everything after the first time it is mentioned and not the last time.

Is there a way to make it so it only removes everything after the last time it is mentioned using sed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trouble is that sed doesn't know whether an appearance of "Apple prices" is the last until it reaches another one -- or the end of the file. But it can collect lines in the Hold Space and defer the decision:

```
sed -n '/Apple prices/{x;/./p;d;};H'
```

**EDIT:** Alternative inspired by @potong's comment:

```
sed '/Apple prices/!{H;d;};x;1d;'
```

Comment: I like this solution, especially since it flip-flops between the pattern/hold spaces. If I were to nitpick I would prefer `b` rather than the `d` from a pedagogic point of view since the dual solution not using the `-n` option would be `sed '/Apple/{x;/./p;d};H;d' file`

Comment: @potong: I'll do you one better; see edit above. One could also do it using `b` without the holdspace, but I think it would be just as cryptic.

Comment: Perfect, just what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: My humble effort that does not use the hold space `sed '/\n/{:a;P;D};:b;$d;N;/\n.*Apple prices/ba;bb' file` most likely GNU specific. As an aside, although it does not apply to this instance, if there were other fruit prices a corner case may appear and an additional command `1h` would need to follow the `H` command, to prevent an unwanted newline at the start of output.

Comment: @potong: Very clever! And here's my shamefully immodest effort that uses neither the holdspace nor testing/branching: `sed '/\nApple prices/{P;D;};N;s/^/\[NEWLINE]/;D' filename` where `[NEWLINE]` is an actual newline (since I know of no cleaner way to insert a newline with the substitution command).

Comment: Are you missing a `-n` option?. You already refer to `\n` in the first regexp, so I see no shame in using it on the RHS of a substitution. If the it's ok on the LHS but not the RHS how about `s/.*\(\n\)/\1&/`?

Comment: @potong: 1) No, a `-n` would make no difference in this case. 2) My version of sed interprets "\n" on the LHS as newline, but on the RHS as "\n", go figure. 3) Hey! You're right! I vaguely remember using that trick before. Sometimes it's awkward, but here it's a definite improvement.

Comment: I thought that the read passed the end of file causes the `N` command to print out the pattern space, thus the need for either the  `-n` option or a `$d` just before the `N` command but this may be GNU specific see [here](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq6.html#s6.7.5)

Answer (score 1):

A common tactic in such cases is to reverse the input line by line, make decision based on first occurrence and then reverse the output again

```
$ # with awk: tac ip.txt | awk 'f; /Apple prices/{f=1}' | tac
$ tac ip.txt | sed '0,/Apple prices/d' | tac
Apple prices
$15.74 p 12
$13.17 p 12
$8.19 p 8
Apple prices
$12.99 p 11
$4.67 p 1
$3.22 p 2
```